# Access current scope from anonymous function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

There is a host of related questions regarding other languages, but this is one is about MATLAB.

(How) can I access the caller's scope from an anonymous function? I had considered using `eval`, but this works even worse than just using the variable. An example:

```
clearvars;
f1 = @() n
f2 = @() eval('n')
n = 1
f3 = @() n
f4 = @() eval('n')
n = 2
```

`f3()` runs, but outputs `1`, while I would like `2`. My preferred solution would be `f2()`, but all of `f1()`, `f2()`, `f4()` fail with almost the same error message:

```
(Error using eval)
Undefined function or variable 'n'.
```

Interestingly, `f4()` cannot even access the original scope, probably because `eval` hides the use of `n` so that `n` is not stored alongside `f4` for memory reasons.

So what can I do to access `n` from `f2`?

Comment: What MATLAB version are you using? At least on MATLAB R2014b, `f3()` works.

Comment: @hbaderts 2016b. Of course, `f3()` works, but you cannot change the value of `n` after defining `f3` (at least, it won't have any effect on `f3`). I'll clarify the question (but note I have an answer already).

Comment: Uhm, anonymous functions are the same thing as ordinary functions. Nobody expects `function bla = foo()` to get n from your workspace, why do you expect it from anonymous functions? When the thingy is created, it gets its values hardcoded in.

Comment: @ZizyArxcher I don't expect them to always do it, but I expect MATLAB to provide a way similar to JavaScript, PHP, ...  And it does, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
clearvars;
f5 = @() evalin('caller', 'n')
n = 2
f5()
```

Read more about the `evalin` command in [the MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalin.html).